# What is the meaning of Future.resolve()?

Tags: javascript, dom, future

W3C just introduced Futures into the DOM standard.

Looking at http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-futureresolver-resolve, I understand that `Future.accept(value)` notifies listeners of success and `Future.reject(exception)` notifies listeners of failure, but what does `Future.resolve(value)` mean/do?

**UPDATE:** I found an excellent tutorial here: http://www.xanthir.com/b4PY0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the spec you've quoted:

`accept(value)` "accepts" a value, it sets the value of the `future` object in that context to whatever value you've accepted. It will then process any accept callbacks using `value`.

`resolve(value)` "resolves" the deferred object, it looks for a `then` attribute in your `value`. If `IsCallable(then)` is true, it calls `then`. It then runs the context object's `accept()` with `value`. If there is no `then`, it will run `reject()`.

So basically `resolve` can call either `accept()` or `reject()` itself.

I hope what I just wrote is clear... The process is a bit more detailed but explained in the spec thoroughly.

Comment: So what you're saying is that users are never supposed to call `accept()` directly. Instead, we're supposed to call `resolve()` which will invoke `accept()` if possible, else `reject()`. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You can call `accept()` but I think in most cases you will call `resolve()` instead. [Here is](http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt1-theory-and-semantics) a nice article about promises and deferred objects.